# Chinese equivalent of "I can honestly say..."

Tags: expressions

Is there a Chinese equivalent of "I can honestly say".

It's a rather colloquial expression, and I was wondering if there were something equivalent in Chinese to convey the same earnestness of the expression, "I can honestly say..."

> I can honestly say I did my best.

I could try for a literal translation, but I want something that a native speaker would say, not Chinglish (or whatever the Chinese equivalent is called :P please comment if you know!).

Answer (score 9):

Below all are fine.

(1)坦白說,...
(2)老實說,...
(3)坦白講,...
(4)老實講,...
(5)說[老]實話...
(6)說真心話...
(7)[我]打從心底說...
(8)[我]敞開心房[向你]傾訴 (more literal, less colloquial)

+我已經盡[全]力了

or

+我已經做到最佳(表現,etc).

If you are writing a formal letter or convey in a more literal way, you may say,

- 我已付諸全力(+以赴).

Answer (score 6):

For 'I can honestly say I did my best.':
  * [说实话]我已经尽力了 or
  * 我[真的]已经尽力了 ←probably the most colloquial one
  *

Answer (score 4):

I think a equivalent for that is 实话说 or 我真的认为.

Answer (score 4):

坦白说（讲），老实说（讲），凭心而论, 实不相瞒

oral forms (Northern dialect):说真的，不瞒您说，说实话，凭良心说，打心眼里说，实话告诉你，说实话，说句老实话，凭良心说

Answer (score 2):

“实话和你说吧，”
 or “实话告诉你，” or "说实话, "都是比较口语的说法。

Answer (score 1):

凭良心讲

C'est juste une phrase contre la censure de langue.

Comment: Répondez en anglais ou s'il vous plaît.

Comment: @deutschZuid Parce que la systeme m'empeche de rependre seulement en chinois, et que pour les questions comme ca, on ne repondre qu'un mot...

Answer (score 1):

In more Chinese term:老實的告訴你 我已經盡力了 (老实的告诉你 我已经尽力了）

Answer (score 0):

As you can see that there are lots of translations, all are prefect translation for *"I can honestly say"*, user43796's list is what I'd choose.

As in the content of *"I can honestly say I did my best"*, 比较口语的说法 is:

> 说真的,我真尽力了

More formal expression **for this specific content** are,

凭心而论, 凭良心说，实不相瞒

"坦白的说（讲）"/ "老实说" was my first choice, until seeing your example. It is more appropriate if the example is something like:

> I can honestly say you are not ugly.

Do **NOT** use “实话和你说吧，” or “实话告诉你，” unless you are expression your intention to **argue** with him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for colloquial expression, these ones are commonly used:

哥们儿，**我不骗你**，我尽全力了。

我尽全力了，**骗你我是小狗**。